# asp.net c# send parameter from my asp page to Data Access layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I´m trying to make a simple filter for my table. I have an aspx page that has a label text. I want to use that text to condition my query. Normally I would just use label.text as the value, but since im working in another layer it won´t work.

How could I make my program understand that it has to use the text from the label of my asp page?

Here´s my code.

```
public static List<DTO.vEmpleado> GetEmpleadoList()
{
    if (//label is empty)
    {
        return DataAccess.Generic.GetAll<DTO.vEmpleado>(); //this works just fine
    }
    else
    {
        return Common.DataContext.vEmpleado.Where(x => x.Nombre == //label.text).ToList(); //this works fine if I replace label.text with something like "Richard"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code around where you are using this method?

Comment: why can't you change the `GetEmpleadoList()` Method to take a string name input.. I think we need to see how you are getting and or passing the label.Text

Comment: That´s pretty much what I want to do. I need help passing my label.text from my asp page to this layer. @MethodMan

Comment: I do not see where the issue is .. I would google how to construct a querystring in asp.net, or how to store values in a Session Variable if you are going to be passing it to a `Page_Load` in a web Application..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of directly reading the control, send that value to your method:

```
public static List<DTO.vEmpleado> GetEmpleadoList(string name)
{
   return Common.DataContext.vEmpleado.Where(x => x.Nombre == name);
}
```

and call it with

```
var list = GetEmpleadoList(label.text);
```